# Start App back at the beginning. Logout functionality

Tags: ios, objective-c, logout

So I have an app that when launched it goes to a LoginViewController once you login, it does a modal transition to a NavigationController where the root is the next MainViewController. If I want to implement the logout functionality, what is the best way to do this? Should I just programmatically do a modal transition back to the LoginViewController or is there a way to easily restart the app back at the starting vc? I am hoping that if I do a modal transition back to the LoginViewController that the MainViewController will not still be running.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "the MainViewController will not still be running"? What is your concern? Views don't generally run. They wait.

Comment: @MarcusAdams well. lets say I have a timer that does an auto-refresh by pulling from the internet every minute. Will the timer still be running if I used a modal transition back to the login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't "go back" using a modal transition -- this doesn't actually go back, it creates a new LoginViewController. You should dismiss the navigation controller if you want to go back to the same instance of the LoginViewController. If you do the modal transition your controller hierarchy will look like this:

LoginViewController --> NavigationController --> MainViewController --> LoginViewController

When you do a modal transition, the presented view controller keeps a strong pointer to the presenting view controller, so all of these controllers will still be "live", and your timer will continue to run.

I would use a different structure. I would make the navigation controller be the root view controller of the window, and present (if you need to) the LoginViewController from the viewDidAppear method of MainViewController. When you're done with it, dismiss it. If you need it again to log out, present it modally again.

Comment: @rdelmar yea, I kind of figured it would happen like that. How do I dismiss the NavigationController from a modal view of the RootViewController? I tried several including `self.parentViewController.navigationController`

Comment: @Alan, I'm not sure what controller you're talking about. Are you in MainViewController, or one that's presented modally from it, or something else?

Comment: @rdelmar Yes I am in the MainViewController, but I am presenting another SettingsViewController modally. So there is a LogOut button in the SettingsViewController. I am trying to go from the SettingsViewController to the LoginViewController.

Comment: @Alan, try  [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: @rdelmar you are the master! never cease to amaze me. Thank you!